# What's the significance of the name Panchashikha?

Tags: mahabharata, etymology, samskara

`Panchashikha` is a character who appears in the Mahabharata. I found the name interesting. A `shikha` is the tuft of hair that remains after an `upanayana` ceremony. Why would someone be named `Panchashikha` (5 shikhas)?

Comment: where to keep shikha differs for sects. some have in back, some top, and one sect keeps 5 shikhas.

Answer (score 1):

'Pancha-sikha' means the following

> A lion
>
> Name of a Gandharva
>
> Name of a Śāṃkhya teacher
>
> Name of an attendant of Śiva
>
> **Having tufts of hair on the head (as an ascetic)**

So it seems to be a part of some ascetic lineage.

Reference: Sanskritdictionary.com